# Angular Universal: Service is unavailable when route has query params

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have an angular 7 project and I'm using Angular universal.
Everything is working fine except when I have query params in my route, angular is not able to recognize the module that it should load.

I have this routes configured:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'after-purchase', loadChildren: 'app/views/after-purchase/after-purchase.module#AfterPurchaseModule' },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
]
```

**after-purchase-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: AfterPurchaseComponent }];
```

When I use `ng serve` everything is ok but when I serve the application using angular universal, the `/after-purchase` route works but `/after-purchase?param=value` doesn't work. It tries to load for some minutes and then it shows the browser `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error.

I also tried it without lazy loading. No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always the problem was with some other point of my code. I had a request sent in `ngOnInit` and that request had a problem.

In order to debug the problem (for anyone who has entered this page by searching) you can look at the errors in console when running `node local.js`.